# Access XML Node Through String

Tags: xml, string, actionscript-3

If I have a string like below, can I use it to reference the node in the XML and how would I go about doing so?

```
var loc:String = "myXML.section.header";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is probably not possible however I will modify the string a bit to conform with your other question

Assuming myXML is the AS3 variable storing your xml.

> var sec:String = 'section'; var head:String = 'header';
>
> myXML[sec][head]

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string at each '.' and then for each substring you can found every node that has a localName equal to it.

In short and using E4X syntax for example you can have a function like this:

```
    function getXMLList(xml:XML, search:String):XMLList {
        var filters:Array = search.split("."); // break your string appart

        // search for all node matching the first name using .() function on XML
        var xl:XMLList = xml.(localName()==filters[0]); 

        // loop over the previous result if there is something found
        for (var i:int=1, l:int=filters.length;i<l && (xl.length() > 0);i++) {
           xl = xl.children().(localName()==filters[i]);
        }

        return xl;
    }
```

then using it:

```
     var xl:XMLList = getXMLList(myXML, 'root.nodeA.nodeB');
```

Here the live example working on wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/sed9